# Scalatra on nginx : how to set up?

Tags: linux, mongodb, nginx, jetty, scalatra

Would like to set up **Scalatra** to run on a box running **nginx**.

Already have nginx set up correctly, and am able to serve static html pages, however, I now wish to point it to a Scalatra app. All of the documents available appear to assume that the server used will be Jetty: for example - http://blog.everythings-beta.com/?p=430

I assume that I cannot simply point it to just the folder because the jetty configuration requires, in addition to this, a class name and a servlet mapping.

How to I **configure nginx** to point to a **Scalatra app**?

Thanks!

---

#### Additional Info:

Ubuntu 12.04 is my operating system - so answers may either be specific to this, or anything that would generally work on **Linux**.

---

#### Bonus:

Throw in **MongoDB** as well - i.e. how to set up nginx with Scalatra and MongoDB - into your answer for extra points!!

Comment: Not a great question as google is your friend here, but I supplied an answer pointing to the documentation for nginx and casbah, that should suffice to get you up and running

Comment: @Ross : Ah, I did come across these when searching, however, I was specifically leaving out stuff that used Jetty. I take it that this means that it is impossible to use nginx to serve scala apps directly? (sorry, for the newbie question, btw)

Comment: No you need to a java webserver to run it then you can proxy via nginx

Answer (score 3):

Setting up with nginx is easy check out the docs on [deploying](http://wiki.nginx.org/JavaServers) java servers.

Once you are up and running install [casbah](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/current/setting_up.html) and you are up and running.

Comment: i love the sentence "Once you are up and running install casbah and you are up and running."... it's a little circular but so typical